# Box3 attached to the camera is not responding to collision with another Box3

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am having problem with detecting intersection between a box3 (which is a wall) and the camera (which is player moving).

Here is the code:

```
            const wallgeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 200, 50 );
            const wallmaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {color: 0x366078, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
            const wall1a = new THREE.Mesh( wallgeometry, wallmaterial );
            wall1a.position.set(40,0,50); wall1a.rotation.y=0.5*Math.PI; scene.add( wall1a );

            const humangeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 3,3, 3 );
            const humanmaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00,  transparent: false, opacity: 1.0} );
            const human = new THREE.Mesh( humangeometry, humanmaterial );
            **scene.add( human );
            var humanhelper = new THREE.BoxHelper(human, 0x00ff00);
            scene.add(humanhelper);
            var humanbox3 = new THREE.Box3();
            humanbox3.setFromObject(humanhelper);
            camera.add(human);**

            var wallhelper = new THREE.BoxHelper(wall1a, 0x00ff00);
            scene.add(wallhelper);
            var box3b = new THREE.Box3();
            box3b.setFromObject(wallhelper);
```

and in animate() function:

```
            humanhelper.update();
            humanbox3.setFromObject(humanhelper);
            if(humanbox3.intersectsBox(box3b))
            {
                console.warn("Collision TRUE");
            };
```

and so I'm going with the camera through the wall but no collision is being detected.
I'm sure that camera wireframe and position is getting updated correctly because it moves along with player (human).
//EDIT
no, actually it looks like the box3 is not being updated at all. I placed 2 walls in the same place, collision was detected, so I started moving one of walls away in animation loop but it was still saying that they are colliding.
[image: Picture of Camera wireframe]

Answer (score 0):

```
humanhelper.update();
```

...will update the geometry of human helper to match human, but not its position.

Since humanhelper is a child of the scene, it will stay in a fixed position and will never trigger the collider.

I think you need to make humanhelper a child of camera or human.  Then it will move along with the camera/human and should trigger the collision you want.

```
human.add(humanhelper);
```

or

```
camera.add(humanhelper);
```

instead of

```
scene.add(humanhelper);
```

should make the difference.